# Definition vs Notation for constants

Tags: coq

I'm extending an existing project (Featherweight Java formalization),
and there are a number of constants, such as:

```
Notation env := (list (var * typ)).
```

What would change if I used `Definition` instead:

```
Definition env := (list (var * typ)).
```

Why did the author use `Notation` here?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you try to apply or rewrite with a lemma, there's a component in Coq called the *unifier* that tries to find out how to instantiate your lemma so that it can work with the situation at hand (and checking that it indeed applies there). The behavior of this unifier is a bit different depending on whether you use notations or definitions.

Notations are invisible to Coq's theory: they only affect the parsing and printing behavior of the system. In particular, the unifier doesn't need to explicitly unfold a notation when analyzing a term. Definitions, on the other hand, must be explicitly unfolded by the unifier. The problem is that the unifier works *heuristically*, and cannot tell with 100% certainty when some definition must be unfolded or not. As a consequence, we often find ourselves with a goal that mentions a definition that the unifier doesn't unfold by itself, preventing us from applying a lemma or rewriting, and having to manually add a call to unfold ourselves to get it to work.

Thus, notations can be used as a hack to help the unifier understand what an abbreviation means without manual unfolding steps.